# SVN to GIT - Multibranch repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am converting an SVN repository to a brand new GIT repository.

The old SVN repo has multiple branches:[image]

I did manage to do a conversion, using the `svn2git` tool.

`git svn clone https://url/to/svn/server --no-metadata --authors-file=authors-transform.txt`

Although, the file history conversion was not successful. On the new GIT repository, I can only see the file history for the determinate folder, not trough all old "svn branches".

How can I migrate those svn folders (branches) to a GIT structure, so that file history can be successful maintained?

Perhaps, make every svn folder a new GIT branch, and keep the latest svn branch as the master branch on the new GIT repo.

Comment: Note that `git-svn` and `svn2git` are **completely** different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-read [git svn docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-eminitem), add **all** required parameters in order to define location(s) of your repo's branches/tags/

Even if `https://url/to/svn/server` is your repo-root and you use default layout, you **must** to define it for clone using additional `--stdlayout` option. If your tree have more complex structure, you have to describe it using separate options.

Answer (score -1):

The right tool for that is called SubGit. It has flexible branches mapping, see docs: https://subgit.com/documentation/branches-mapping.html